# Fail to build image using spring-boot:build-image

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, image

I know that there was an article about such a problem, but it does not help me. So the proble that i can't build spring boot project image using buildpack(spring-boot:build-image). I got such a message:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ---------------------< pr.ivan.microservice:order >---------------------
[INFO] Building microservice-order 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> spring-boot:3.2.1:build-image (default-cli) > package @ order >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- resources:3.3.1:resources (default-resources) @ order ---
[INFO] Copying 1 resource from src\main\resources to target\classes
[INFO] Copying 0 resource from src\main\resources to target\classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- compiler:3.11.0:compile (default-compile) @ order ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- resources:3.3.1:testResources (default-testResources) @ order ---
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\MonitoringProject\microservice-order\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- compiler:3.11.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ order ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- surefire:3.1.2:test (default-test) @ order ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- jar:3.3.0:jar (default-jar) @ order ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot:3.2.1:repackage (repackage) @ order ---
[INFO] Replacing main artifact D:\MonitoringProject\microservice-order\target\order-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar with repackaged archive, adding nested dependencies in BOOT-INF
/.
[INFO] The original artifact has been renamed to D:\MonitoringProject\microservice-order\target\order-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar.original
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< spring-boot:3.2.1:build-image (default-cli) < package @ order <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot:3.2.1:build-image (default-cli) @ order ---
[INFO] Building image 'docker.io/library/order:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
[INFO]
[INFO]  > Pulling builder image 'docker.io/paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-base:latest' 100%
[INFO]  > Pulled builder image 'paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-base@sha256:92811b61280130099527b40c7650c871187a7e1cebb21744d93e480fc34cbcb0'
[INFO]  > Pulling run image 'docker.io/paketobuildpacks/run-jammy-base:latest' 100%
[INFO]  > Pulled run image 'paketobuildpacks/run-jammy-base@sha256:ac21741202c46c4de193714557e692ce29fa5a2f70047d4799deb7e21ac99d89'
[INFO]  > Executing lifecycle version v0.18.4
[INFO]  > Using build cache volume 'pack-cache-ce6629fb170a.build'
[INFO]
[INFO]  > Running creator
[INFO]     [creator]     ===> ANALYZING
[INFO]     [creator]     Image with name "docker.io/library/order:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT" not found
[INFO]     [creator]     ===> DETECTING
[INFO]     [creator]     6 of 26 buildpacks participating
[INFO]     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/ca-certificates   3.6.7
[INFO]     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/bellsoft-liberica 10.4.4
[INFO]     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/syft              1.42.0
[INFO]     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/executable-jar    6.8.3
[INFO]     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/dist-zip          5.6.8
[INFO]     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/spring-boot       5.27.8
[INFO]     [creator]     ===> RESTORING
[INFO]     [creator]     ===> BUILDING
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]     Paketo Buildpack for CA Certificates 3.6.7
[INFO]     [creator]       https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/ca-certificates
[INFO]     [creator]       Launch Helper: Contributing to layer
[INFO]     [creator]         Creating /layers/paketo-buildpacks_ca-certificates/helper/exec.d/ca-certificates-helper
[INFO]     [creator]     
[INFO]     [creator]     Paketo Buildpack for BellSoft Liberica 10.4.4
[INFO]     [creator]       https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/bellsoft-liberica
[INFO]     [creator]       Build Configuration:
[INFO]     [creator]         $BP_JVM_JLINK_ARGS           --no-man-pages --no-header-files --strip-debug --compress=1  configure custom link arguments (--output must 
be omitted)
[INFO]     [creator]         $BP_JVM_JLINK_ENABLED        false                                                        enables running jlink tool to generate custom J
RE
[INFO]     [creator]         $BP_JVM_TYPE                 JRE                                                          the JVM type - JDK or JRE
[INFO]     [creator]         $BP_JVM_VERSION              19                                                           the Java version
[INFO]     [creator]       Launch Configuration:
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_DEBUG_ENABLED           false                                                        enables Java remote debugging support
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_DEBUG_PORT              8000                                                         configure the remote debugging port
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_DEBUG_SUSPEND           false                                                        configure whether to suspend execution until a 
debugger has attached
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_HEAP_DUMP_PATH                                                                       write heap dumps on error to this path
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JAVA_NMT_ENABLED        true                                                         enables Java Native Memory Tracking (NMT)      
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JAVA_NMT_LEVEL          summary                                                      configure level of NMT, summary or detail      
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JFR_ARGS                                                                             configure custom Java Flight Recording (JFR) ar
guments
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JFR_ENABLED             false                                                        enables Java Flight Recording (JFR)
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JMX_ENABLED             false                                                        enables Java Management Extensions (JMX)
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JMX_PORT                5000                                                         configure the JMX port
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JVM_HEAD_ROOM           0                                                            the headroom in memory calculation
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JVM_LOADED_CLASS_COUNT  35% of classes                                               the number of loaded classes in memory calculat
ion
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JVM_THREAD_COUNT        250                                                          the number of threads in memory calculation    
[INFO]     [creator]         $JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS                                                                        the JVM launch flags
[INFO]     [creator]         Using Java version 19 from BP_JVM_VERSION
[INFO]     [creator]       No valid JRE available, providing matching JDK instead. Using a JDK at runtime has security implications.
[INFO]     [creator]        : Contributing to layer
[INFO]     [creator]       Warning: Dependency has no SHA256. Skipping cache.
[INFO]     [creator]         Downloading from
[INFO]     [creator]     unable to invoke layer creator
[INFO]     [creator]     unable to get dependency
[INFO]     [creator]     unable to download
[INFO]     [creator]     unable to request
[INFO]     [creator]     Get "": unsupported protocol scheme ""
[INFO]     [creator]     ERROR: failed to build: exit status 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  12.327 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-01-25T23:12:06+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.2.1:build-image (default-cli) on project order: Execution default-cli of goal org.s
pringframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.2.1:build-image failed: Builder lifecycle 'creator' failed with status code 51 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

Here is my pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>pr.ivan.microservice</groupId>
    <artifactId>order</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>microservice-order</name>
    <description>microservice-order</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>19</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <version>8.2.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <image>
                        <env>
                            <BP_JVM_VERSION>${java.version}</BP_JVM_VERSION>
                        </env>
                    </image>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Note, that i'm using java 19 in my project + java 19 in pom.xml and i checked this, because there was such a solution post

Comment: Note that most vendors don't support JDK 19 any more and you might want to switch to 21.

Answer (score 0):

see [Paketo Buildpack for BellSoft Liberica 10.4.4](https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/bellsoft-liberica/releases/tag/v10.4.4).There doesn't seem to be a jre 19 version.You can change it to jre 17 or jre 21 and try it.

Comment: So i need to change my real штыефддув project jdk to 17, not only in pom.xml?

Comment: @CoovShow You can specify it by setting BP_JVM_VERSION via pom.xml.